In the Contingency argumemt it is referenced that alternative having things can not be necessary, whats the alternative in here can be considered as?
In the Argument of Contingency there is referenced that if something has alternatives, that thing can't be necessary because of it could be something different than what it is, so is this information sensible and if it is, are me and you are considered as alternatives as being humans? I think yes but I am not sure, it is like good god, bad god they both different. Can different entities in same form(like humans, gods, matters) considered as alternatives?

Can you spell out or link this argument from contingency with "alternatives" in it? SEP's version has no "alternatives" in it and neither does Pruss's version of Leibnizian cosmological argument. It is unclear what it means for things to be each other's alternatives. When we say that a thing is contingent we typically mean that there is an alternative world without the thing, not that there is an alternative thing.

Yeah, there was one video and few articles about it in William Lane Craig's argument avout contingency, https://youtu.be/ytCduIccswQ?si=qQZTybXkMvPhsXLh                 https://www.reasonablefaith.org/question-answer/P240/could-the-universe-not-god-be-the-necessary-being

In a nutshell I argue that because a different collection of fundamental particles could have existed instead of the ones that do exist, a different universe could have existed instead of this one. The atheist who tries to avoid Leibniz’s conclusion by holding that the universe is metaphysically necessary is thus thrust into the position that every sub-atomic particle that exists is metaphysically necessary, which seems highly implausible, to say the least.

Here is Craig's argument from contingency, and it also has no "alternative things". Moreover, he says:"As we look about the universe, none of the things that make it up, whether stars, planets, galaxies, dust, radiation, or what have you, seems to exist necessarily. They could all fail to exist; indeed, at some point in the past, when the universe was very dense, none of them did exist." In other words, he also uses the usual sense of contingency - there could be a different world without those things.

Yeah you are right sir, I made the word alternative to call what he said, Sir if that is the case can we say numbers are alternative to each other and if they are can they be necessary since it has alternatives( we can move with different examples too sir)?

We can say that numbers or humans are not alternatives to each other, and it is best not to use this word at all. But there are no possible worlds without numbers (on the standard conception), while there are possible worlds without humans, so numbers are necessary and humans (and stars, planets, galaxies, dust, radiation) are contingent.

Well, it's kinda tricky. The Argument of Contingency, like most things in philosophy, has sparked tons of debate and different interpretations, so it depends who you ask, really. For philosophers like Aquinas, who use this argument to prove God's existence, God is the only necessary being, while everything else, like us humans, falls under "contingent." Like, we exist because God created us, but God doesn't need us to exist, you know?
But here's where it gets kinda fuzzy. Even within a group like humans, we're all unique, right? So are we alternatives to each other? There's no single "human blueprint" that we all have to fit. It's kinda like that good god/bad god example you brought up. They both might be considered "gods" in a broad sense, but their specific characteristics make them totally different entities.
So, it boils down to how you define those categories and what you consider essential to their existence. It's all about interpretation, and philosophy is kinda notorious for having tons of that!
